# Send on-hold order status email notification to admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I want the admin to receive **on hold** order notification as well in WooCommerce. Right now, only customers get that notification.

I have tried the following codes but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);
function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    if ($object == 'customer_on_hold_order') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: My name <my@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

What should be the correct filter/hook to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct **`$email_id`** for **"on-hold"** order status email notification is **`'customer_on-hold_order'`**.

So your code is going to be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_admin_email_notification', 10, 3);
function custom_admin_email_notification( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {

    if( 'customer_on-hold_order' == $email_id ){
        // Set HERE the Admin email
        $headers .= 'Bcc: My name <my@email.com>\r\n';
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works.

---

Similar answers: [How to get order ID in woocommerce_email_headers hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738772/how-to-get-order-id-in-woocommerce-email-headers-hook/39741446#39741446)

Comment: Can this be modified for other statuses too that are sent to the customer?

Comment: @WaliMuhammadKhubaib Yes it can be - some other related answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+email_id

Answer (score 0):

It has been 3 years and the WooCommerce states seem to have changed. I tried using the new states `customer_on-hold_order` => `pending_to_on-hold` or `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold`, but no emails came and the headers were not changed. so I resulted in just using single words for the check:

```
// Send on-hold order status email notification to admin
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_admin_email_notification', 10, 3);
function custom_admin_email_notification( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {

    if( strpos($email_id,'hold') > 0 ){
        $headers .= 'Bcc: Admin User <admin@example.com>'. "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

I thank you **@LoicTheAztec**, however for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The correct $email_id for "on-hold" order status email notification is NOT 'customer_on-hold_order' as sugested in the answer bellow (sorry no reputation to comment) but the right one is 'customer_on_hold_order'

So change the on-hold to on_hold