# WooCommerce email notifications: different email recipient for different cities

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I using Woocommerce and actually I receive order notifications only to one email. I would like to receive notifications about orders in 2 different emails depending on customer location:

- For customer from zone 1 (Germany) I would like to receive the email notifications at 
  **`Mail #1 (mail1@mail.com)`**,
- For all other zones like zone 2 (Mexico) I would like to receive the email notifications at 
  **`Mail #2 (mail2@mail.com)`**.

I looking for some functions on net, but I was find only funtcions to send to two email adresses, but without any If condition.

What I will need is something like that:

```
if ($user->city == 'Germany') $email->send('mail1@mail.com')
else $email->send('mail2@mail.com')
```

Which hook can I use to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: That is just example, what I meant

Comment: The example you provided looks fine.  So what are you asking for help with?  Can you provide more code so it makes the problem you are having more clear?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_email_recipient_{$this->id}`** filter hook, targeting **'New Order'** email notification, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'diff_recipients_email_notifications', 10, 2 );
function diff_recipients_email_notifications( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Set HERE your email adresses
    $email_zone1 = 'name1@domain.com';
    $email_zone_others = 'name2@domain.com';

    // Set here your targeted country code for Zone 1
    $country_zone1 = 'GE'; // Germany country code here

    // User Country (We get the billing country if shipping country is not available)
    $user_country = $order->shipping_country;
    if(empty($user_shipping_country))
        $user_country = $order->billing_country;

    // Conditionaly send additional email based on billing customer city
    if ( $country_zone1 == $user_country )
        $recipient = $email_zone1;
    else
        $recipient = $email_zone_others;

    return $recipient;
}
```

> For WooCommerce 3+, some new methods are required and available from `WC_Order` class concerning billing country and shipping country: **`get_billing_country()`** and **`get_shipping_country()`** …
>   **Usage with $order instance object**:
>
> ```
> $order->get_billing_country(); // instead of $order->billing_country;
> $order->get_shipping_country(); // instead of $order->shipping_country;
> ```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Code is tested and works.

---

Related answers:

- [How to get order ID in woocommerce_email_headers hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738772/how-to-get-order-id-in-woocommerce-email-headers-hook/39741446#39741446)
- [Send on-hold order status email notification to admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916182/send-on-hold-order-status-email-notification-to-admin/41917582#41917582)