# WooCommerce order status processing then send an email to custom email along with customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I want to send an email to custom email address when order status changed to processing along with customer email ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use a custom function hooked in
>   `woocommerce_email_recipient_{$this->id}` filter hook, targeting
>   'customer_processing_order' email notification, this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'wh_OrderProcessRecep', 10, 2);

function wh_OrderProcessRecep($recipient, $order)
{
    // Set HERE your email adresses
    $custom_email = 'mycustomemail@domain.com';

    $recipient = $recipient . ', ' . $custom_email;
    return $recipient;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Reference:

1. [Adding a second email address to a completed order in WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92030/103815)
2. [Customising WooCommerce notification emails with hooks and filters](http://www.mootpoint.org/blog/customising-woocommerce-notification-emails-hooks-filters/)
3. [WooCommerce email notifications: different email recipient for different cities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41948372/5019802)

Hope this helps!