# Send Woocommerce new order email notification from specific user role to specific user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, email-notifications

We have a **"main wholesaler"** who is in charge of other wholesalers.  This wholesaler is assigned to user role:  **wholesale_customer** just as the other wholesalers.
This **"main wholesaler"** places orders for his stores, and the other wholesalers place orders for their own stores as normal.

I would like that the **"main wholesaler"** receive an email notification when the other wholesalers place their orders, so he will get notified when other wholesalers are ordering because he gets a commission.

So is there a way that we can make the **"main wholesaler"** to receive an email notification when the other wholesalers place their orders?

Maybe this can be done with a function somewhat like this:
[WooCommerce email notifications: different email recipient for different cities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940348/woocommerce-email-notifications-different-email-recipient-for-different-cities)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** *(solved a bug in backend email settings)*

The following function will send an additional "new order" email notidfication to the "Wholesale manager" when others `wholesale_customer` user roles will make a purchase.

You will just need to set in this function the User ID for the "Wholesale manager"…

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wholesale_manager_email_recipient', 20, 2 );
function wholesale_manager_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $recipient;

    // Only for 'wholesale_customer' user role
    if( is_admin() || ! user_can( $order->get_user_id(), 'wholesale_customer' ) )
        return $recipient; // Exit if not a 'wholesale_customer'

    // HERE Set the main wholesale manager user ID
    $manager_id    = 5;

    $manager_user  = new WP_User( $manager_id );
    $manager_email = $manager_user->user_email;

    // Add manager email when other 'wholesale_customer' place orders
    if ( $order->get_user_id() != $manager_id )
        $recipient .= ',' . $manager_email; // coma separate emails

    return $recipient;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.