# Additional email addresses to on hold status email notification for BACS payments

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, I would like to have in "on hold" email notifications, 2 additional emails addresses (pref. bcc), so that they can be monitored for payment.

It is for any orders using BACS so that the relevant people can be notified to keep an eye on thing. I can find all sorts on order complete but not on hold email.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is possible using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_email_headers`** filter hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_admin_email_notification', 10, 3);
function custom_admin_email_notification( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {

    // Targeting "on hold" order status only with BACS payments
    if( 'customer_on-hold_order' == $email_id && 'bacs' == get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) ){
        // Set HERE your additionals emails in this array:
        $emails = array('Name1 <name1@email.com>', 'Name2 <name2@email.com>');

        // Adding the new emails to 'Bcc' headers
        $headers .= 'Bcc: '.implode(',', $emails).'\r\n';
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

Related answers:

- [How to get order ID in woocommerce_email_headers hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738772/how-to-get-order-id-in-woocommerce-email-headers-hook/39741446#39741446)
- [Send on-hold order status email notification to admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916182/send-on-hold-order-status-email-notification-to-admin/41917582#41917582)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work I am afraid. Still only get the standard emails.