# Woocommerce - customize email sender based on order meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I'm developping a plugin for a client relative to woocommerce:

To be short, it display a complexe form that allow customers to book a storage box in a specific location (several locations are available).

In this context, since a box is located on a particular location site,
I would like to be able to set the email expeditor (or at least the reply to address) depending on which site the box is located.

This way, if the customer decide to reply to the email, it will automatically sent the reply to the corresponding location site address.

**Here is a more "illustrated" way of explaining what I'm trying to do:**

- "Box A" is located on "Site 1" (email: **site1**@domain.ext)
- "Box B" is located on "Site 2" (email: **site2**@domain.ext)

So if the customer book the "Box A", the order confirmation email should be sent from : site1@domain.ext

But if he book the "Box B", it should be sent from : site2@domain.ext

My issue is that I can't find any hook that gives me access to the WC_Order object (or at least it's id), the email is related to.

I tried using the filter "woocommerce_email_headers" as it has 3 parameters :

- `$headers` : actuel headers of the email
- `$email_id` : the email identifier
- `$object` : the object the email is related to (could be product, customer, ...)

unfortunatelly it seems, from the [code reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-emails.html#source-view.637), that it is never used for the 'customer_processing_order' email, so it looks like a dead end.

Anyone has already try to achieve this (and maybe succeed) ?

Ideally I would like to have something like this:

```
/**
 * Customize email expeditor (headers) for corresponding site expeditor
 * Function hooked to a filter/or action
 *
 * @param string $headers   Current header
 * @param string $email_id  email identifier
 * @param WC_Order $order   Order
 * 
 * @return string; 
 */
public function wc_customize_email_headers( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {
    
    if( $email_id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
        // Do the magic using $order
        // and customize the headers if needed
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

**Edit:**

As suggested by @7uc1f3r I tried to adapt the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741446/11987538), but it doesn't work.

I manage to check, through logs that the headers returned by the function are indeed set as I want :

```
From: Site 1 <site1@domain.ext>
```

Though the email I recieve still come from the default admin email.

Here the function I use:

```
/**
 * Customize email expeditor (headers) for corresponding site expeditor
 *
 * @param string $headers   Current header
 * @param string $email_id  email identifier
 * @param WC_Order $order   Order
 * 
 * @return string;
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'wc_customize_email_headers', 10, 3);
function wc_customize_email_headers( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {
    
    // Get order id and order
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    if( in_array( $email_id , [ 'customer_processing_order', 'new_order' ] ) ) {
       // Do the magic to set header : ex
       $site_expeditor = 'From: Site 1 <site1@domain.ext>";
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: just make it no-reply and put a support email adress inside the email

Comment: @FUZIION yeah that would be my last solution but I would like to have a more intuitive solution for the customer if I can.